# javascript - need little help to read multiple values by multiple buttons in single input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

hello i need little help to read multiple values by multiple buttons like 1,2,3 and output in input like this 123 not only 1 number, concurnete number by every click

```
<input type="button" onclick="changeText(1)" value="1" >
<input type="button"  onClick="changeText(2)" value="2">
<input type="button"  onClick="changeText(3)" value="3">
<br>
<input type="text" id="count" value=""/>

function changeText(value) {
    document.getElementById('count').value = value ;
}
```

floowed by next number

link demo
http://jsfiddle.net/J7m7m/541/

Comment: [`java` != `javascript`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)

Comment: Do you mean like `132121` ?

Comment: You mean, like that ? http://jsfiddle.net/J7m7m/542/

Comment: yes i do like 132121 increase by every click

Comment: increase the amount you click or append the value at the end?

Comment: solved like this http://jsfiddle.net/J7m7m/542/ tnkx   Karl-André Gagnon

Answer (score 1):

```
function changeText(value) {
    document.getElementById('count').value += value ;
}
```